# Keep rows with one particular value in one column using some condition in another column in same dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, filter, apache-spark-sql, multiple-columns

I have the below dataframe:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Device1 | A | true |
| Device1 | A | false |
| Device1 | C | false |
| Device1 | B | false |

I want to keep first two rows (where col2 value = A) where A is identified because col3 has a 'true' in row 1. In other words, for device 1, I want to keep all those rows where col2 has at least 1 value in col3 as 'true'.
I expect the below result after the filter:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Device1 | A | true |
| Device1 | A | false |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with window functions: partitioning by col1 and col2, ordering by col3 descending. Use the [**`first`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.first.html#pyspark.sql.functions.first) function over the window.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('Device1', 'A', True),
     ('Device1', 'A', False),
     ('Device1', 'C', None),
     ('Device1', 'B', False)],
    ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

w = W.partitionBy('col1', 'col2').orderBy(F.desc('col3'))
df = df.withColumn('keep', F.first('col3').over(w))
df = df.filter('keep').drop('keep')

df.show()
# +-------+----+-----+
# |   col1|col2| col3|
# +-------+----+-----+
# |Device1|   A| true|
# |Device1|   A|false|
# +-------+----+-----+
```